# How to make image with cut corners?

Tags: css

Is it real to make image with cut-off corners?

```
<div>
  <img src="somepic" />
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/

Comment: You could read through this: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: one example from your structure http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KNzrzY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, if you just want to give an image rounded corners, you can declare a `border-radius` (without actually giving the image a `border` of any width).

If you are explicitly looking to create an image with cut-off corners like the one displayed in your question, you can achieve this effect with an `::after` pseudo-element, which is transparent, has a border and is rotated 45 degrees.

In the example below there are three images.

- The first image has no `border`, but it does have a `border-radius`
  applied.
- The second image has an `::after` pseudo-element, which is transparent, has a white border and is rotated 45 degrees.
- The third image is the same as the second image, but the border of the pseudo-element is red, so you can more clearly see what is going on and how the effect works.

```css
img {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color:rgb(0,0,0);
}

div {
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
margin-right:72px;
}

div:nth-of-type(1) img {
border-radius: 12px;
}

div:nth-of-type(n+2)::after {
content:'';
display:block;
position:absolute;
top:-30px;
left:-30px;
width: 124px;
height: 124px;
border: 18px solid rgb(255,255,255);
transform:rotate(45deg);
}

div:nth-of-type(3)::after {
border: 18px solid rgb(255,0,0);
}
```

```html
<div><img src="http://static.pexels.com/photos/67211/field-away-summer-sky-67211.jpeg" /></div>
<div><img src="http://static.pexels.com/photos/67211/field-away-summer-sky-67211.jpeg" /></div>
<div><img src="http://static.pexels.com/photos/67211/field-away-summer-sky-67211.jpeg" /></div>
```